# Don't Require preceeding zeros when entering in combo box

Tags: ms-access

I have some combo boxes that require user input.  In Access 2000 I am linking to our ERP database (FoxPro) via ODBC.  So, I cannot modify the table structure at all.  For whatever reason, a lot of the fields have leading zeros.  I have ***Limit To List*** set as ***Yes*** on the combo boxes.

Sample of the combo boxes:

[image]

I would like it if the user did not have to enter the leading zeros.  However, if the user where to enter 47009, they would get the error:

```
The text you entered isn't an item in the list.
```

The fields are text and my row source looks like:

```
SELECT recid, recnum FROM receiver ORDER BY recnum;
```

and I am binding to the first column.

**Is there a way I can force the user to what is in the list and not require them to enter the leading zeros?**

Comment: In the access database I am storing recid which is text.  In FoxPro both the recid and recnum are text fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the combo box's Row Source, you can use a query which discards the leading zeros from the `recnum` field string values.  Stripping those zeros is easy with a regular expression in a custom VBA function.  Here is an Immediate window demonstration of the `StripLeadingZeros()` function included below.

```vb
? StripLeadingZeros("000000AV1-00011")
AV1-00011
? StripLeadingZeros("000000TI1-00035")
TI1-00035
```

So you can use that function in a query such as this ...

```sql
SELECT recid, StripLeadingZeros(recnum) FROM receiver ORDER BY 2;
```

With that query as the combo box's row source, the user will not see the leading zeros.  If they do need to see, but not type, the leading zeros, you could add `recnum` again by itself as a third column.

If your string values contained *only* digits, the task would be simpler.  You could use the `Val()` function to cast those strings as numbers.  You could still use `StripLeadingZeros()`, but `Val()` should be faster.

```sql
SELECT recid, Val(recnum) FROM receiver ORDER BY 2;
```

```vb
Public Function StripLeadingZeros(ByVal pstrInput As String) As String
    Static re As Object
    If re Is Nothing Then
        Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        re.pattern = "^0*"
    End If
    StripLeadingZeros = re.Replace(pstrInput, vbNullString)
End Function
```

Comment: +1, almost there.  Works perfectly for the Receiver number since it will always be a number.  However, the PO number is not always a number.  Here are a couple of examples of the non number POs: `000000AV1-00011`, `000000TI1-00035`, and `000000AV2-00016`.  For these the `Val()` always equates to `0`.  Any ideas on how to get these captured as well?  I would prefer them to show as `AV1-00011`, `TI1-00035`, and `AV2-00016`.

Comment: Here is a query that gets me most of the way there: `SELECT ponum, Val(ponum) FROM pomain WHERE IsNumeric(ponum) ORDER BY Val(ponum) UNION SELECT ponum, ponum FROM pomain WHERE IsNumeric(ponum) = false ORDER BY ponum`.  It removes the 0s on the ponum that are numeric and does not set 0 for the ones that are not.  But it does not remove the zeros in front of the non numeric ponums.

Comment: In the pomain table the ponum is the primary key.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  You are right Val() is 3 times faster than StripLeadingZeros()